# Histogram indicating 20~25% in a certain range

Tags: graphs, histogram

This is a histogram of speeds of certain ships drawn to the density scale:

[image]

I was told that the percent of speeds in the [17, 18) range is between 20 and 25, but I believe it's between 30 and 50. Can anyone convince me wrong?

Comment: I count twelve bars that each account for more than 10% of the density. Something is off about the graph.

Answer (score 1):

Histograms are not reliable methods to communicate summary statistics because it depends on bin size choice.

The best option to answer numerical questions to find the raw numerical data.